# How to get Validators to allow white space?

Tags: html, css, angular

The problem is that my angular code triggers an error on the form controls when I add a white space to the text input.I would like the regex to allow white spaces. I've tried several different regex patterns. I believe the one im currently using should be allow letters and whitespaces.

**TypeScript**

```
form = this.fb.group({
    title: [,[Validators.required,Validators.pattern("[a-zA-Z\s]+")]],
    author: [,[Validators.required,Validators.pattern('/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/')]],
    description: [,Validators.required],
    date: [new Date]
})
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="title"> Article Title </label>
    <span 
        style="color: red;font-style: italic" 
        *ngIf="(mouseOverSubmit || form.controls.title?.touched) 
        && form.controls.title?.errors?.required"> 
        Required 
    </span>
    <span 
        style = "color:red;font-style: italic" 
        *ngIf= "form.controls.title?.touched 
        && form.controls.title?.errors?.pattern"> 
        Only letters and numbers allowed
    </span>
    <input (ngModel)="title" 
            name="title" 
            formControlName="title" 
            class="form-control"
            type="text" 
            id="title">
</div>
```

Comment: I'm sure you would need to escape the the backslash in the pattern, because it is inside a string. Try changing `\s` to `\\s`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is [validator](https://stackblitz.com/edit/trailing-whitespace-validator) example for you

`\s`    Any Whitespace

`\S`    Any Non-whitespace character

Answer (score 0):

Use in this way `Validators.pattern("^[a-zA-Z ]*$")`

To allow only one space between two words use in this way 
 `Validators.pattern("^[\w+ ?]*$")`

Comment: How would you handle tabs, returns etc.? These all are under the category of _whitespace_.